# Quadratic equation with complex number as a parameter

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I used the formula for a quadratic equation, but the square root was problematic to solve this problem. It supposed to be done without trigonometry.
$$z^2-(2+i)z-1+7i=0$$

Comment: Treat $i$ as a constant and proceed as with any quadratic equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

We can simply apply the quadratic formula which holds also for complex numbers

$$az^2+bz+c=0\implies z=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

then

$$z=\frac{(2+i)\pm\sqrt{(2+i)^2-4(-1+7i)}}{2}$$

For the calculation of the square roots we can use trigonometric form

$$w=r(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta) \implies \sqrt w=\sqrt r\left(\cos \left(\frac{\theta}2+k\pi\right) + i \sin \left(\frac{\theta}2+k\pi\right)\right) \quad k=0,1 $$

Comment: but I got complex number under the square root, how to get rid of it?

Comment: @NemanjaDjordjevic We need to calculate the square root of the complex number.

Comment: Hmm let $z = x+iy = \sqrt{(2+i)^2-4(-1+7i)}$. Find $z^2$ and compare real and imaginary parts.

Comment: @NemanjaDjordjevic see my answer for that

Answer (score 0):

Use Quadratic Formula to get:

$$z=\frac{(2+i)\pm\sqrt{7-24i}}{2}$$

Then use the following result:
$$\text{Let}\space (a+bi)^2=c+di$$
$$\text{Then}\space a=\pm\sqrt{\frac{c\pm\sqrt{c^2+d^2}}{2}}$$
$$\text{And}\space b=\pm\sqrt{\frac{-c\pm\sqrt{c^2+d^2}}{2}}$$

Checking the signs as you go.

This result can be proven without the use of trigonometry (and indeed, I did not know about polar forms when I found it)

Comment: Note that **NOT** all of those will work, only some will, but check them all in case they do.